# How to Data Defined Override rotation of symbol with autocad map 3D rotation attribute?

Tags: qgis, autocad-map

I am exporting a .shp from autocad to QGIS. The drawing in CAD looks like a line with symbols within the line. When exporting to QGIS the symbols turn to points and the line has breaks. Also, the points are no longer parallel to the line it is on and slightly offset.
My current work-around is to create a new field(ROTATION) and select the points that run N to S and assign them 90. I do this for E to W and the few symbols that are aligned diagonally. I then data used defined override to correlate the rotation field with the rotation of the symbols. I finish it off by selecting offset points (basically all of them) and move them.

I tried exporting the .shp with the rotation property but the field values that look like this: ROTATION (0.049377440710162) or (0.068036433659789). These numbers are obviously not going to rotate properly in QGIS.

Is there a workaround Im missing here? Making these edits is time consuming.
Is there a way to assign rotation easily? either within CAD before exporting or in QGIS.

Comment: Please provide screenshots showing the differences.